# DBML error : Invalid object name 'dbo.SPNAME'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am using dbml to manage database operations.

I have used and worked with over 50 + sp's using this dbml and all seems to work fine.

Today I added a new sp to the dbml file and when that sp is executed I get a runtime error which says...

> SqlException was unhandled by user code
>
> Invalid object name 'dbo.SPNAME'.

Below is all what I have verified.

- The db user which I have mentioned in the connection string has access to this sp.
- Have executed the sp in SQL Server Management Studio using the same credentials and the sp works.
- I am using the correct "Initial Catalog" and "Data Source".

What could be the problem ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: refresh your dbml file or just close project and run again..might be it taking time to refresh details...

Comment: I am having problem with this particular sp only.. this problem is for more than a week now, so I have refereshed dbml added other sp etc...

Comment: Check the `SQL profiler`

Comment: Error got resolved, I just removed the sp and re added it again and it works now :)